# Magento 2.2.4 Customer are unable to logout

Tags: magento2, form-key, logout

i´ve just installed a fresh Magento2 on my webspace to prepare the migration of my Magento 1.9.

I installed my theme (Infortis) and created my products and did the first test-salse. Everything fine...

But if I try to logout as a Customer this error appears:

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Notice: Undefined index: form_key in vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerFlushFormKey.php on line 48

Since there isn't even a valid google result on this file, I hope that you can tell me what to do.

Comment: Answer from user (=OP?): "This is really strange...

I wanted to test the issue again this morning before disabling all extensions/themes one by one.

The Error is gone. Do you think it is possible that over night just a wrong session cache got purged or something like that?

--solved :) --"

Answer (score 4):

What I did to fix the issue is that I went to this file: /vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerFlushFormKey.php

and, on line 48 with the ff. codes:

```
if ($beforeParams['form_key'] == $currentFormKey) {....}
```

I added a checker for the $beforeParams['form_key']:

```
if (!empty($beforeParams['form_key']) && $beforeParams['form_key'] == $currentFormKey) {...}
```

This is just a band-aid fix for me to proceed on logging out. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi everyone just to update this comment! We addressed this issue to Magento 2 Support and they were able to provide us with a patch for this!

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a theme, the issue can be:
- the theme has an issue and you may want to put a request to infortis support
- the issue may also be due to the server setup but quite unlikely. To check out this possibility, you may search for errors: server error log
--> it is worthwhile trying to isolate what is the origin of the issue: I would disable the theme to get started and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is really strange...

I wanted to test the issue again this morning before disabling all extensions/themes one by one.

The Error is gone. Do you think it is possible that over night just a wrong session cache got purged or something like that?

--solved :) --

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in magento 2 It's resolved in this PR: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/16386/files/90e37b59cce7e07a4aee3a5bbc9a00b10aaa58a6

If you want fix this bug in your project you can override the plugin vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerFlushFormKey.php and change the condition in line 48 to

if (isset($beforeParams['form_key']) && $beforeParams['form_key'] === $currentFormKey) {